# ASP.NET Button Control to Trigger Client-side Code which, In Turn, Triggers Server-side Code

Tags: asp.net, postback

I've seen a lot of related questions, but don't seem to be able to figure out what to do here.

I have an asp hidden field control defined as

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hField" runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>
```

and a button control defined as:

```
<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" usesubmitbehavior="false" onClientClick="return jsFunc()"/>
```

The JavaScript function looks something like this:

```
function jsFunc() {
    document.getElementById( "hField" ).Value = "someString";
    __doPostBack( "btn1", "" );
 }
```

Finally, in my code behind, I have the following function:

```
Protected Sub btn1_Click( ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
    ' // access hidden field hField 
End Sub
```

but the problem is that the value I assigned to the hidden value in the javascript is not persisting the postback.

What do I need to understand or what do I need to do so that the updated hidden field value persists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is easy. Javascript is case sensitive, so when you use Value property of hidden element, it creates new property **Value** instead of setting it to **value** property.

So, you just need to update code to follow:

```
function jsFunc() {
   document.getElementById("hField").value = "someString";
   __doPostBack( "btn1", "" );
}
```

Comment: Can't believe how easy that was!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call `__doPostBack()` from your javascript function. Instead the javascript function should `return false` in case you want to cancel/prevent the PostBack.

Comment: It does return false; it's a callback which calls `__doPostBack`.